# Adding extra field to UNION ALL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a series of database tables corresponding with various websites and sections - e.g. MySite/World, MySite2/World, MySite3/People, etc.

I'm merging all these projects together into a new website. But to make the project work, I need to preserve each DB table's identity - the name of each database table's original website and section - in my query. In another thread, someone on stackoverflow showed me how to derive static values from database tables (e.g. Select 'GZ' AS GSiteID). So I wound up with the following query (though it actually queries more tables than I've listed below):

```
 $stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 'GZ' AS GSiteID, 'Life' AS GSection, GZL.Taxon AS URL
  FROM gz_life GZL WHERE GZL.Taxon = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'All' AS GSiteID, 'World' AS GSection, GG.Name FROM gw_geog GG WHERE GG.Name = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GS' AS GSiteID, 'World' AS GSection, GS.URL FROM gs GS WHERE GS.URL = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PX' AS GSiteID, 'People' AS GSection, Ppl.URL FROM people Ppl WHERE Ppl.URL = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PX' AS GSiteID, 'Orgs' AS GSection, PXO.URL FROM orgs PXO WHERE PXO.URL = :MyURL");
 $stm->execute(array(
 'MyURL'=>$MyURL
 ));

while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
```

It works fine, but there's a catch. The tables **people** and **orgs** are actually associated with multiple websites. For example, there might be an article about Abraham Lincoln (URL = Abraham_Lincoln) in a political website and an article about some famous explorer in a geography website. Or there might be TWO articles about a politically active scientist, one in the political website and another in a science website.

Thus, the tables people and orgs have an extra field named **Site**. Most of the values for both are **PX**, though **SM** is another common value, and there are others.

The query I posted above identifies EVERYTHING from the tables people and orgs as **PX**. I'd like to know if there's some way I can add those extra Site fields to the query, modifying it so that a particular row from the table people or org is correctly identified as PX, SM, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `site` to each subquery and assign it a value of `NULL` where it is not used:

```
  SELECT 'GZ' AS GSiteID, NULL as Site, 'Life' AS GSection, GZL.Taxon AS URL
  FROM gz_life GZL WHERE GZL.Taxon = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'All' AS GSiteID, NULL as Site, 'World' AS GSection, GG.Name FROM gw_geog GG WHERE GG.Name = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GS' AS GSiteID, NULL as site, 'World' AS GSection, GS.URL FROM gs GS WHERE GS.URL = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PX' AS GSiteID, Site, 'People' AS GSection, Ppl.URL FROM people Ppl WHERE Ppl.URL = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PX' AS GSiteID, Site, 'Orgs' AS GSection, PXO.URL FROM orgs PXO WHERE PXO.URL = :MyURL");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'GZ' AS GSiteID, 'Life' AS GSection, GZL.Taxon AS URL
  FROM gz_life GZL WHERE GZL.Taxon = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'All' AS GSiteID, 'World' AS GSection, GG.Name FROM gw_geog GG WHERE GG.Name = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GS' AS GSiteID, 'World' AS GSection, GS.URL FROM gs GS WHERE GS.URL = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Site AS GSiteID, 'People' AS GSection, Ppl.URL FROM people Ppl WHERE Ppl.URL = :MyURL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Site AS GSiteID, 'Orgs' AS GSection, PXO.URL FROM orgs PXO WHERE PXO.URL = :MyURL
```

That way, the other three tables (gz_life, gw_geog, and gs) will have the default values, and table/row specific values will be included for people and orgs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `SELECT Site AS GSiteID`.... instead of `SELECT 'PX' AS GSiteID`...

`Select 'Something' as Name` is just selecting a hardcoded literal string and giving it a name as if its a column.  So if you want the actual column, use the column name (`SELECT Site`) rather than a literal.  And if you want to rename the column in your returned dataset, `Select realcolumnname as newcolumnname`...